# cucumber rails failing a case

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rspec, cucumber, ruby-on-rails-3.2, capybara

I have the following scenario in feature:

```
@home
Feature: Home page

@home
Scenario: User launches home page
  Given a user visits the home page
  And user is not signed in
  Then he should see user signin information
```

Am seeing 2 problems:
1) When I run `rake cucumber --tags @home`, it throws an error: `invalid option: --tags`

So, I run with `cucumber --tags @home`
2) It is throwing the following error:

```
Given a user visits the home page             # features/step_definitions/home_steps.rb:2
And user is not signed in                     # features/step_definitions/home_steps.rb:23
Then he should see user signin information    # features/step_definitions/home_steps.rb:6
  expected link "User Sign In" to return something (RSpec::Expectations::ExpectationNotMetError)
  ./features/step_definitions/home_steps.rb:8:in `/^he should see user signin information$/'
  features/home.feature:8:in `Then he should see user signin information'
```

However, when I launch and see in browser, I can see and click the link and I verified the step to make sure there are no spelling mistakes or extra spaces.

> Can some one help me how I can debug this?

Steps:

```
Given /^a user visits the home page$/ do
  visit home_path
end
Given /^user is not signed in$/ do

end

Then /^he should see user signin information$/ do
  page.should have_link('User Sign In', href: user_signin_path)
end
```

Comment: you can try debugging your app by adding `save_and_open_page` right before the page.should have_link clause. that will open a browser page and you'll see what cucumber 'sees' right before it checks for your expectation.

Comment: Thanks, that solved the issue of why the case is failing. By the way, can you tell me why the execution with rake is failing?

Comment: rake is different from cucumber. the rake task basically just calls cucumber - you can run cucumber itself. Rake is sort of a convenience/short cut method to run ALL your tests. If you need to pass options to cucumber (tags, specific files), just call cucumber itself. I hope that cleared it up :)

Comment: Sure I understand that part. What I was trying to understand is the difference between running `cucumber` and `rake cucumber`. It is possible that running with rake is processing --tags as a rake option. Will do a little bit more reading. Please add your comment as answer and I will accept. It did solve my problem

Comment: If I remember correctly, rake uses a different syntax when accepting options/arguments. it would probably be more on the side of `rake cucumber tags=@home` IF it was possible. Best thing would be to check your Rakefile or Cucumber's Rakefile on how to call it properly :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try debugging your app by adding `save_and_open_page` right before the `page.should have_link` clause. That will open a browser page and you'll see what cucumber 'sees' right before it checks for your expectation.